# Correct way to avoid duplicates in a Redis channel

Tags: transactions, redis, publish-subscribe, duplicates

I've a system where multiple publishers are putting data into the same Redis channel. All publishers are publishing the *same type of message* but with different content. Each message has a unique id. However, multiple publishers can put the same message (i.e., having the same message id) into the channel.

I want to avoid duplicates in the channel so that the subscribers only get unique messages. Is there a way to configure Redis channels to avoid duplicates?

If not, this is what I was planning to implement. 
Keep a `SET` of message ids in Redis. In a Redis *transaction*, each publisher must check the SET for the message id before putting it into the channel.

If someone has a better idea or can point out flaws in my approach I would appreciate that.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean for the each client to check the set for the *string* instead of the message id? If so your approach sounds find.  The only suggestion I would make is to use a hash of the message instead of the message itself as the set operations will be faster.

Comment: I think keeping a set is a reasonable way and I don't think pubsub can be configured to avoid duplicates. By the way, why should "subscribers" put the same message into the channel? Is this just a typo error or have I missed something?

Comment: @WeiLi - yeah it's a typo - I meant multiple publishers.

Comment: @LeeAvital - No I meant message id only. Message ids are generated by another upstream system and multiple publisher can have the exact same message. And since message ids will always be unique I can just use that instead of the hash of the message string as you recommended.

Comment: This is how I finally resolved this issue. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220035/redis-exception-with-transactions-with-jedis-client